# Export few pages as a new PDF file from original one in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have PDF files with more than 200 pages. I want to implement a web service with PHP that export a new PDF file with few pages from original file.

In another word, assume that `A.pdf` file have 200 pages and I want to input this file to web form and output 20 pages (page 40 ~ page 60) as a new PDF file named `A_part.pdf`.

I found few PHP libraries such as TCPDF and FPDF etc. for the purpose. But don't get how to do.

Comment: i wouldent use php, its going to be low, there are several free command line tools to do this (if you have server access0

Comment: Have you had a go and failed? People on this site often prefer to help debug code examples rather than debate tools and approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider the [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) command line toolkit. It got pages ranges options:

```
pdftk myDocument.pdf cat 1-9 26-end output removedPages.pdf
```

The full documentation is [available here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk) and [a post about it](https://www.linux.com/learn/manipulating-pdfs-pdf-toolkit) I found useful could also help.

A [PHP library exists on Github](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk). It should wrap the features that interest you:

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

// Extract pages 1-5 and 7,4,9 into a new file
$pdf = new Pdf('/path/to/my.pdf');
$pdf->cat(1, 5)
    ->cat(array(7, 4, 9))
    ->saveAs('/path/to/new.pdf');
```